# Existence of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $f$ and $g$ be bilinear forms on a finite dimensional vector space $V$. Suppose $g$ is non-degenerate. Show that there exists unique linear operator $S$ and $T$ on $V$ such that
$$ f(a,b)=g(Sa,b)=g(a,Tb) $$  for all $a,b \in V.$

What happens if $g$ is degenerate?

Comment: Hint for finding $S$: Fix $a$. The function $b\mapsto f(a,b)$ is linear function from $V$ to the base field $K$. You should be familiar with the result that all linear functions $V\to K$ are of the form $b\mapsto g(x,b)$ for some $x\in V$. This is because $g$ is non-degenerate. Define $S(a)=x$, where $x$ has the property $f(a,b)=g(x,b)$ for all $b\in V$. Prove that the resulting $S$ is linear. Then do the same with $T$.

Comment: If $g$ is degenerate, then the solution is non-unique.